# O correto é nasci "a" ou "aos"?

Tags: concordância, literatura

Em *A menina sem estrela* escreve Nelson Rodrigues :

> Nasci a 23 de agosto de 1912, no Recife, Pernambuco.

É correto escrever "nasci a 23"? Ou o correto seria *nasci aos 23 *[dias]* de agosto*?

Comment: Olha, eu falo "nasci em 24 de fevereiro" ou "nasci no dia 24 de fevereiro"...

Comment: Ovide, por que *dia* em «nasci aos 23 dias de agosto» está no plural? Em todos esses anos nessa indústria vital, essa é a primeira que isso me acontece.

Comment: @Schillive Busco precisamente a forma gramaticalmente correta de constuir a formulação "nasci a/aos/em", que desconheço. Parece-me que teriam decorrido 23 dias depois do primeiro dia de agosto, por isso o hipotético plural em "aos 23 [dias] de agosto". Mas, não sei se é correto.

Comment: @ovide, correto, correto, «nasci a 23 de agosto» deve ser correto, já que *a* é a preposição mais genérica que tem e usa-se *à segunda-feira*. A frase «nasci aos 23 dias de agosto» não me semelha ter sentido — quanto ao que te referes —, também porque *23* em *dia 23* é um jeito de falar vigésimo terceiro dia de agosto (inglês: ***twenty second** of Agust*). Já «nasci a 20 dias de agosto», me parece dizer «nasci no dia 25 de agosto», mas é ambigüíssimo. Por sinal, demorei para responder porque escreveste *Schillive*, com dois ll — escrevo errado sempre.

Comment: @Schilive Obrigado pela sua opinião. Uma rápida busca no Google, no entanto, permite encontrar inúmeras ocorrências com "nasci aos". Por exemplo, "nasci aos 9 de agosto de 1896 em Neuchâtel, na Suíça" ; "Nasci aos 11/07/1971 em Serra Talhada", etc. Não é uma formulação completamente inaudita. Não sei se é incorreta do ponto de vista gramatical.

Comment: @ovide, fiz uma resposta, mas não sei se realmente é uma resposta.

Comment: @Schilive Muito obrigado!

Comment: O meu comentário desapareceu: Se diz: Eu nasci **no día x de [mes]**. Deve ter sido porque eu disse "credo e gente". Portanto, é verdade: nascer no día 2 de novembro de [ano] é o mais comun e o mais correto.  Alias, em português, a pergunta é: **[em] Que día você nasceu**? Ou: [em] Que dia nasceste?

Comment: @Schilive Não, e me parece francamente incrível no sentido que nào vejo nada feio ou mal educado dizer na fala ordinária, "Credo e gente". Outro ponto incrível é que para mim o mais idiomático é: no dia [x] de [mes]. Como o autor de A Menina Sem Estrela vem do Pernambuco e tinha uma grande carreira como escritor, talvez assim se diga por aqueles lares. Não sei.

Comment: Francamente, você acha que o bot está programado para reconhecer "credo e gente"?? "credo" em português não é insulto, e "credo, gente" é coloquial e reconhecedor de um **grupo**. Não se diz "gente" a pessoas fora de um grupo. "Gente" é chegado a um tom de amizadade, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Gramáticas e dicionários não me dizem se é melhor desta ou daquela maneira. Na literatura as formas ***nascer a, nascer em*** e ***nascer no dia*** são de longe as mais comuns; ***nascer aos*** também se encontra, mas menos, especialmente na forma *aos X dias*. Todas as formas se encontram do século XIX ao presente. Seguem-se alguns exemplos de entre as catrefadas que encontras no Google Books (negrito meu e grafia original em todas as citações).

### Nascer a

> O Vice-Presidente de Pena foi Nilo Procópio Peçanha, um campista **nascido a 2 de outubro** de 1867 e **falecido a 31 de março** de 1924.
> [Edson Monteiro, Trajetória Histórico-Social da Engenharia Brasileira, 2019](https://books.google.pt/books?id=eZ6gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&dq=%22nascido%20a%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi024_Bvb70AhWh4IUKHbFyB-g4FBDoAXoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22nascido%20a%202%22&f=false)
>
> Lindolf Bell — **Nasceu a 2 de novembro** de 1938 , em Timbé, Santa Cararina
> [União Brasileira de Escritores, 1982](https://books.google.pt/books?id=W0QtAAAAYAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&dq=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc6eCmub70AhV4AWMBHbnvD-44PBDoAXoECBQQAg)
>
> Camilo Miguel de Lima e Silva, **nasceu a 2-11-1815**.
> [Revista Genealógica Brasileira, 1944](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uOMRAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ3raRuL70AhWGsBQKHWCsBgoQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&f=false)
>
> O Sr. D. Pedro II, Imperador Constitucional e Defensor Perpetuo do Brazil, **nasceu a 2 de Dezembro** de 1825 e sucedeu no throno a seu pae **a 7 de Abril** de 1831.
> [*O Imperio do Brazil na Exposição Universal de 1873*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=IOBTYFpN7YcC&pg=PA65&dq=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP2srstb70AhXtDmMBHUHSAhMQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20a%202%22&f=false)

### Nascer em

> **Nasceu em 2 de novembro** de 1904, em Bragança Paulista (SP)
> [Schuma Schumaher e Érico Vital Brasil, *Dicionário Mulheres do Brasil*, 2000](https://books.google.pt/books?id=83DTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&dq=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE_YXbyL70AhWBAGMBHVWyA004FBDoAXoECA8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&f=false)
>
> **Nasceu em 2 de maio** de 1974 na cidade de São Paulo
> [Placar Magazine, 1997](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ExTATo6k5LoC&pg=PA50-IA8&dq=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5rpKkx770AhWh4YUKHUKCD2gQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&f=false)
>
> **Nasceu em 2 de abril** de 1918, em S. Paulo
> [Anuário Genealógico Brasileiro, 1947](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6CfTAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA376&dq=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5rpKkx770AhWh4YUKHUKCD2gQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&f=false)
>
> **Nasceu em 2 de Agosto** de 1824. Casou em o 1.º de Maio de 1843
> [Almanak Administrativo, Mercantil e Industrial, Rio de Janeiro, 1852](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2JMVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqhMGyxr70AhUNHxoKHSsrATsQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20em%202%22&f=false)

### Nascer no dia

> Dener Augusto de Souza **nasceu no dia 2 de abril** de 1971 na Zona Norte de São Paulo.
> [Placar Magazine, 2005](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CPMUwx_Zj1gC&pg=PA21&dq=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDyrvN1L70AhUHtRoKHagFAEUQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&f=false)
>
> João Bosco Vidigal Santana. **Nasceu no dia 2 de fevereiro** de 1954. Universitário de Medicina na UFJF.
> [Pedro Maciel Vidigal, *Os Antepassados*, 1980](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9d0rAAAAYAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&dq=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibw7Ck1b70AhVSzRoKHRdUBvAQ6AF6BAgJEAI)
>
> Filha do Imperador D. Pedro I e da Imperatriz D. Leopoldina, **nasceu no dia 2 de agôsto** de 1824, no então Palácio Imperial, onde hoje está situado o Museu Nacional
> [Revista Militar Brasileira, 1947](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDyrvN1L70AhUHtRoKHagFAEUQpwV6BAgBEC8&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1)
>
> Ha duas coincidencias notaveis em dous factos da existencia do dr. Sigaud : **nasceu no dia 2 de Dezembro** , no dia em que deveria nascer aquelle Principe de quem mais tarde viria a servir como subdito , e **formou-se no dia 7 de Setembro**, n’um dia anniversario da independencia de sua nova patria ;
> [Revista do Instituto Historico e Geographico do Brazil, 1856](https://books.google.pt/books?id=eHeq07b-FSMC&pg=RA1-PA152&dq=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSj8_V1r70AhXNzYUKHTdTAsAQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20no%20dia%202%22&f=false)

### Nascer aos (sem *dias*)

> O padre José Francisco Rezende Dias **nasceu aos 2 de abril** de 1956 nem Brasópolis (MG).
> [Comunicado mensal da Conferência Nacional dos Bispos do Brasil, 2001](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MmBaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20aos%202%22&dq=%22nasceu%20aos%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2_Z_7wr70AhUJKBoKHVEiDo84FBDoAXoECAQQAg)
>
> **Nasceu aos 2 de agosto** de 1918 em Cuiabá, no Estado de Mato Grosso.
> [Revista brasileira de entomologia, 1983](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WSklAQAAMAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20aos%202%22&dq=%22nasceu%20aos%202%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0kZKLwr70AhWQA2MBHeHfDAUQ6AF6BAgLEAI)
>
> Alberto André Delpino, que **nasceu aos 10 de agôsto** de 1868
> [Revista do Instituto Histórico e Geográfico de Minas Gerais, 1948](https://books.google.pt/books?id=QgY0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20aos%22&dq=%22nasceu%20aos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj176aiwL70AhWMxIUKHQv1DxkQ6AF6BAgPEAI)
>
> D. Francisco Cardoso Ayres **nasceu aos 18 de Dezembro** de 1821, na freguesia de S. Frei Pedro Gonçalves desta cidade.
> [Revista do Instituto Archeologico e Geographico Pernambucano, 1868](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uBkTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA526&dq=%22nasceu%20aos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw9Mm9v770AhVD14UKHd8yB-44FBDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22nasceu%20aos%22&f=false)

### Nascer aos (com *dias*)

Estes são mais raros, tive de estender mais a rede. Claramente mais frequentes no século XIX do que depois. Mesmo no século XIX eram menos frequentes do que as outras formas.

> […] carioca da gema, é natural desta cidade do Rio de Janeiro, que era então a capital do Império, e onde êle **nasceu aos vinte dias do mês de abril** do ano de 1845.
> [Revista do Instituto Histórico e Geográfico Brasileiro, 1958](https://books.google.pt/books?id=k58RAAAAIAAJ&q=%22nasceu%20aos%20vinte%20dias%22&dq=%22nasceu%20aos%20vinte%20dias%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA1YnBxL70AhUOxoUKHX5LD14Q6AF6BAgCEAI)
>
> […] e tendo sido essa Convenção mutuamente ratificada, trocando-se as ratificações **aos vinte e oito dias do mez de Agosto** do corrente anno
> [Collecção de Leis do Imperio do Brazil, Rio de Janeiro, 1880](https://books.google.pt/books?id=jpEwAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA459&dq=%22aos%20vinte%20e%20oito%20dias%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8-JP-zr70AhXXAGMBHT5bC1kQ6AF6BAgTEAI#v=onepage&q=%22aos%20vinte%20e%20oito%20dias%22&f=false)